# SQL Server - Compare dates or datetime stored as a string or nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I made a date according to the datetime format. But, I stored this in my DB as a string/nvarchar and not a datetime. Will I be able to compare such dates ? Is this a bad practice ?

I am using nvarchar to store a datetime as of now.

Comment: Like what others said, while you can still cast/convert and compare this can be dangerous if the consuming code writes out a different format for your date. While you can control what format can be put in, all of us forget what code we wrote down the road. So you might put in a different format in the near future and everything will be a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can still be able to compare them but this is certainly a bad practice because you will need to convert this strings into dates data type to be able to compare between them. If you have indexes define on the column, they will not be used anymore since the column will be converted and it will cuase slow performance on large database.

An example on comparing dates is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  CONVERT(DATETIME, dateSTRColumn, XXX) > GETDATE()
```

where `XXX` is the current format of the date stored as string.

Comment: *follow-up question: what is the format of date stored in your table?*

Comment: no, that's not what i mean. Is it `mm/dd/yyyy`, `yyyy/mm/dd`? or what?

Comment: jw -  datetime YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn] as mentioned here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: give this a try `SELECT convert(varchar(20), dateSTRColumn, 121) FROM tableName if it gives value`

Comment: jw - The query works. To get the millis also, I used - SELECT convert(varchar(23), dates, 121) FROM dbo.Dates . How difficult will it be to convert dates to datetime and then compare them ?

Comment: Since it works, you can now simply compare them using this: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE convert(varchar(20), dateSTRColumn, 121) >= GETDATE()` or what ever you like. It's not difficult to change the data type but it will likely perform slow because it kills the index if you have define on that column. What it means is it performs full table scan on the table and it is very slow for large databases.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use either [cast or convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to parse a datetime from the strings or compare the raw strings directly. The latter is possible depending on what format the strings are stored as. For example, if dates were stored in the format 'YYYYMMDD' you could simply compare string1 < string2.