# Timestamp stored as Varchar, query range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL server table written to by ForceTen LMS. In it are stored some timestamps. However, they are stored as Varchar in this format:

```
Starttime               EndTime
2005-10-12-21.40.37     2005-10-19-16.44.05
2005-10-12-21.40.57     2005-10-21-12.48.35
```

How can I query a range for the EndTime?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE EndTime >= :param1 AND EndTime < :param2
```

Do not admonish me for the storage of timestamps as Varchar, I did not create this table and CANNOT modify it or the code that writes to it. If you want to blame someone, blame the authors of the ForceTen LMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [SQL Server - Compare dates or datetime stored as a string or nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673764/sql-server-compare-dates-or-datetime-stored-as-a-string-or-nvarchar)

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  CONVERT(DATETIME, dateSTRColumn, XXX) > GETDATE()
```

where XXX is the current format of the date stored as string.

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, EndTime, YYYY-MM-DD-hh.mm.ss) >= :param1 AND CONVERT(DATETIME, EndTime, YYYY-MM-DD-hh.mm.ss ) < :param2
```

Comment: No format that matches the string, did you not look at it?

Comment: @MB34 this should be the answer you are looking for, just one thing for the third convert parameter, be sure to use the exact style that your database uses. I think you need 121, but check it out yourself. Cheers

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: tried 121 and no go. The problem is the extra '-' between the date and time values. See my answer that I actually got from my buddy's over at Experts Exchange.

Comment: He still gave you the right answer, it just needet a bit modification with a replace, thats why i said , check it out yourself.

Comment: your date isn't 2005-10-21-12.48.35 ? so YYYY-MM-DD-hh.mm.ss format ? or i am missing something in my understanding?